# How can I decide, if I should use the Power BI API to push data into my streaming dataset or Azure Stream Analytics?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I am very new to Azure. I need to create a Power BI dashboard to visualize some data produced by a sensor. The dashboard needs to get updated "almost" real-time. I have identified that I need a push data set, as I want to visualize some historic data on a line chart. However, from the architecture point of view, I could use the Power BI REST APIs (which would be completely fine in my case, as we process the data with a Python app and I could use that to call Power BI) or Azure Stream Analytics (which could also work, I could dump the data to the Azure Blob storage from the Python app and then stream it).
Can you tell me generally speaking, what are the advantages/disadvantages of the two approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure stream analytics lets you have multiple sources and define multiple targets and one of those targets could be Power-BI and Blob ... and at the same time you can use windowing function on the data as it comes in. It also provides you a visual way of managing your pipeline including windowing function.

In your case you are kind of replicating the incoming data to Blob first and secondly to power-BI. But if you have a use case to apply windowing function(1 minutes or so) as your data is coming in from multiple sources e.g. more than one sensor or a senor and other source, you have to fiddle around a lot to get it working manually, where as in stream analytics you can easily do it.

Following article highlights some of the pros and cons of Azure Analytics...
https://www.axonize.com/blog/iot-technology/the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-azure-stream-analytics-for-iot-applications/

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would recommend streaming data to IoT Hub first, and then ASA can pick it up and render the same on Power BI. It will provide you better latency than streaming data from Blob to ASA and then Power BI. It is the recommended IoT pattern for remote monitoring, predictive maintenance etc , and provides you longer term options to add a lot of logic in the real-time pipelines (ML scoring, windowing, custom code etc).